# Action on component in view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-routing

How can I seamlessly and elegantly add a hash to the URL with React when the user is viewing a particular section?

Suppose the user visits https://localhost.local. When the user scrolls down to the section with ID "abstract", the URL bar should show https://localhost.local#abstract. When the user scrolls down to the section with ID "introduction", the URL bar should show https://localhost.local#introduction. When the top of the browser screen is above the section with ID "introduction", the URL bar should show https://localhost.local#abstract. When the user scrolls to the top of the page, the URL bar should show https://localhost.local.

In other words, the URL bar shows a hash which contains the id of the section being viewed.

I can do this by using `setInterval()` and checking if `Section["body"].top.y <= window.y < Section["body"].bottom.y` and then modifying the hash of the URL. This method is not very efficient nor elegant.

```
<body>
    <Header />

    <Section id="abstract">
        This is an example.
    </Section>

    <Section id="introduction">
        Efficient way to add query param when component in view.
    </Section>

    <Section id="body">
        Can use setInterval() and check if Section["body"].top.y <= window.y < Section["body"].bottom.y
    </Section>

    <Section id="conclusion">
        Ask fellow Stackexchange users for advice.
    </Section>
</body>
```

The main purpose of this is to allow users to quickly bookmark the section they are viewing.

Comment: You could try looking into using the Intersection Observer API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API within the lifecycle methods and refs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use 3rd party library to simplify the logic, say this one: https://github.com/gabergg/react-scrollable-anchor.